# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. google play

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, google-play, google-play-console

Please, help me.
When I updated the app in Google Play Console it was rejected because I changed the App signing key.
Technical support is not answering me.
Is there a way to change the App signing key without deleting the app?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to recover your Signing Key instead of creating a new one. If you lost it then  you have to communicate with the Google Play Store team and follow the steps that they asked to do.

[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#:~:text=If%20you%20lose%20your%20original,key%20to%20verify%20your%20identity](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20you%20lose%20your%20original,key%20to%20verify%20your%20identity).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. A device with the app installed can't receive an update with a different signature.
Try to recover the last one...